# error when installing docker on raspbian stretch

Tags: raspberry-pi, docker, raspbian

I am trying to install docker on a rpi4 but I have this error when I run

`sudo apt-get install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io -y`

I have

```
Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status docker.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript docker, action "start" failed.
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2021-02-15 19:44:36 GMT; 14ms ago
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
  Process: 9174 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 9174 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
dpkg: error processing package docker-ce:armhf (--configure):
 installed docker-ce:armhf package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of docker-ce-rootless-extras:armhf:
 docker-ce-rootless-extras:armhf depends on docker-ce; however:
  Package docker-ce:armhf is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package docker-ce-rootless-extras:armhf (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for systemd (241-7~deb10u6) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.5-2) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.28-10) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 docker-ce:armhf
 docker-ce-rootless-extras:armhf
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

My journalctl logs

```
$ journalctl -fu docker
-- Logs begin at Thu 2019-02-14 10:11:58 GMT. --
Feb 15 19:44:43 raspberrypi4 dockerd[9311]: failed to start daemon: error initializing graphdriver: driver not supported
Feb 15 19:44:43 raspberrypi4 systemd[1]: docker.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Feb 15 19:44:43 raspberrypi4 systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Feb 15 19:44:43 raspberrypi4 systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
Feb 15 19:44:45 raspberrypi4 systemd[1]: docker.service: Service RestartSec=2s expired, scheduling restart.
Feb 15 19:44:45 raspberrypi4 systemd[1]: docker.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 4.
Feb 15 19:44:45 raspberrypi4 systemd[1]: Stopped Docker Application Container Engine.
Feb 15 19:44:45 raspberrypi4 systemd[1]: docker.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Feb 15 19:44:45 raspberrypi4 systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Feb 15 19:44:45 raspberrypi4 systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
```

What's wrong ?

Comment: By increasing the log level and/or enabling debug logging, you should get more information in the journal. See https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/#enable-debugging.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49099625/docker-error-initializing-graphdriver-driver-not-supported deals with similar graphdriver errors

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue just after having installed the kernel headers. If you did the same, remember to restart your RasPi, then check the service status

```
sudo systemctl status docker.service
```

I also prefered to specify the host in `/etc/docker/daemon.json`, see [here](https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/#enable-debugging) for more details.

So I had to remove the `-H` option in the `systemd` unit config (`/lib/systemd/system/docker.service`)

Not sure about what exactly did the trick, but everything was up and running after the reboot. Not sure it is a permanent fix, as this file can be modified by your next `apt upgrade` or `apt install docker-ce`.